# Retrofit 2 doesn't perform a request

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, rx-java2, dagger-2

My app is needed to connect to **GitHub.com** using **OAuth 2.0**. So I created the next API model:

```
interface IGitHubApi {
    @GET("login/oauth/access_token")
    fun getAccessToken(
        @Query("client_id") clientId: String = GitHub.CLIENT_ID,
        @Query("client_secret") clientSecret: String = GitHub.CLIENT_SECRET,
        @Query("code") code: String
    ): Single<String>
}
```

*I know I can provide a some class that will describe JSON structure and **Gson** will deserialize it automatically but I wanna see a simple JSON (as string).*

After I created a component and module for **Retrofit 2**:

```
@Component(modules = [GitHubApiModule::class])
interface IGitHubApiComponent {
    fun getGitHubService(): IGitHubApi
}

@Module
class GitHubApiModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideGitHubApi(retrofit: Retrofit): IGitHubApi {
        return retrofit.create(IGitHubApi::class.java)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRetrofit(gsonConverterFactory: GsonConverterFactory,
                        rxJava2CallAdapterFactory: RxJava2CallAdapterFactory): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(GitHub.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(gsonConverterFactory)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(rxJava2CallAdapterFactory)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideGson(): Gson {
        val gsonBuilder = GsonBuilder()
        return gsonBuilder.create()
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideGsonConverterFactory(gson: Gson): GsonConverterFactory {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideRxJava2CallAdapterFactory(): RxJava2CallAdapterFactory {
        return RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
    }
}
```

and connected **Dagger 2** to my view model:

```
class AccountViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    var label: ObservableField<String> = ObservableField()
    var isLoading: ObservableBoolean = ObservableBoolean(true)
    var progress: ObservableInt = ObservableInt(0)
    private var gitHubApi: IGitHubApi = DaggerIGitHubApiComponent.create().getGitHubService()

    private fun getErrorMsg(app: Application, hasAccount: Boolean): String {
        return if (hasAccount) {
            app.getString(R.string.err_account_update_failed)
        } else {
            app.getString(R.string.err_account_creation_failed)
        }
    }

    fun createOrUpdateAccount(authorizationCode: String?) {
        val app = getApplication<App>()
        val accountType = app.getString(R.string.account_type_git)
        val accountManager = AccountManager.get(app.applicationContext)
        val accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType(accountType)

        label.set(app.getString(R.string.msg_account_creating))

        if (authorizationCode == null) {
            val msg = getErrorMsg(app, accounts.isNotEmpty())
            label.set(msg)

            return //Break operation
        }

        gitHubApi.getAccessToken(code = authorizationCode)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeBy(
                onSuccess = {
                    label.set(it)
                    progress.set(100)
                    isLoading.set(false)
                },
                onError = {
                    Log.e("AccountViewModel", it.message?: "Could not retrieve an access token.", it)
                    val msg = getErrorMsg(app, accounts.isNotEmpty())
                    label.set(msg)
                }
            )
            .dispose()
    }
}
```

When I run my app I just see `Creating an account...` label that means `onSuccess` and `onError` methods weren't called.

What am I doing wrongly? It must call `onError` at least and there is not any related errors in `LogCat`.

I've checked in debugger app retrieves an authorization code, it's not `null`.

Comment: What's the point of your immediate `dispose()`?

Comment: @laalto, do I need to call it inside `onSuccess` and `onError`? Sorry, it's my first project with RxJava and Dagger, I am a noobie still.

Comment: `dispose()` cancels your call before it get submitted - I believe you should not have it at all.

Comment: @laalto, just AndroidStudio asks to call this method but `ViewModel` hasn't destructor so I don't know where should I call it?.

Comment: @Шах keep track of all disposables (maybe using a `CompositeDisposable`) and call `dispose()` on it in an overriden `onCleared` method

Comment: @WilliamReed, I've introduced a private field `disposable` and call `dispose()` on result if it wasn't disposed.

Comment: @Шах sounds right to me. just one thing of note, you don't need to check if it has been disposed yet you can just dispose immediately as the operation is idempotent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primary reason: `dispose()` is essentially a cancel, and you won't receive success or error event after disposing.

> AndroidStudio asks to call this method

`subscribeBy()` is annotated with `@CheckReturnValue` and Studio complains that you're ignoring the returned `Disposable`.

For fire-and-forget requests you can ignore the disposable and suppress the IDE warning.

If you want to scope the request and to be able to cancel it e.g. when navigating to another screen, you can store the `Disposable` to a variable and call `dispose()` on it in an appropriate lifecycle method. If you have multiple such requests, you can use `CompositeDisposable` to bundle them together.

In your comments you state you have a `ViewModel`. In a `ViewModel`, you can override `onCleared()` and dispose the call there.